# DocuSign Sender Not Receiving Notifications

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect, docusignapextoolkit

We are currently using DocuSign Apps Launcher in Salesforce. We have a DocuSign sender that isn't receiving any notifications, despite having all Sender and Signer notifications checkboxes checked in their preferences at account.docusign.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notifications can be set account-wide or per-user. So there are **two places** to check for notifications. Make sure both are set!

1. Under "My Preferences" (from top-right menu). you'll see Notifications on the left-hand side, looks like this:
   [image: List item]
2. Go to the "Settings" panel (administrators only) and "Signing and Sending" find "Email Preferences":
3. [image: List item]